# Wordpress post counter button giving undefined Ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been wrestling with trying to understand how the Ajax POST system works with data callbacks. Unfortunately for my flawed attention span I keep getting into 3000 word articles and forget what I'm doing there.

Following this tut, http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-post-rating-system-with-wordpress-and-jquery/

What I get is what seems to work on the execution of the page. The little heart icon rolls over to the nice image and when completely loaded, there are no errors in console.

But when I click the heart icon, I get this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ajax_var is not defined
```

From what I'm trying to understand, the following isn't being registered when the script is loaded within the `head`

```
wp_enqueue_script('like_post', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/post-like.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', 1 );
wp_localize_script('like_post', 'ajax_var', array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
));
```

`ajax_var` is being called when the user clicks on the `a` heart, but shouldn't it already be clearly defined from the within `functions.php`?

Live page: theciv.com/vancouver

Comment: Is there any live page that we can see?

Comment: @MasterAM Sure. Added above.

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems that the extra data is not being sent to the browser. If you can step through the code, make sure that the data (which appears to be scalar, as it should be) is indeed attached to the script node and when is it 'dropped'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first localize your script then enqueue it.
To to the it's best to start of with registering your script as such:

```
wp_register_script('like_post', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/post-like.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', 1 );
wp_localize_script('like_post', 'ajax_var', array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
));
wp_enqueue_script('like_post');
```